# How do I select data that does not have a null record?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, equipment and circulation. The equipment table lists all of the equipment I have available for users to borrow. The circulation table lists all of equipment that has been, or currently is, borrowed. When equipment is checked-out it adds the equipment_id to the circulation table. The circulation table has a NULL value in the return_date column. When equipment is returned it adds the date to the return_date column. Because of this the equipment_id can be in many rows. But, only one row would ever have the equipment_id with a NULL value in return_date.

What I am trying to do is find only the equipment_id where it is not out, no NULL value in the return_date column in any row.

Currently I can only seem to get every equipment_id since at some point the equipment went out and there is a NOT NULL value in the return_date column.

I feel that some UNION or JOIN will help with this but I am a novice with MySQL and I can't seem to figure this one out.

Here is an example of what I am talking about.

```
 Equipment Table                 Circulation Table
+--------------+-------------+  +---------------+--------------+-------------+
| equipment_id | name        |  |circulation_id | equipment_id | return_date |
+--------------+-------------+  +---------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1            | Screwdriver |  | 1             | 4            | 2019-07-16  |
| 2            | Hammer      |  | 2             | 2            | 2019-07-23  |
| 3            | Wrench      |  | 3             | 4            | 2019-07-24  |
| 4            | Pry Bar     |  | 4             | 1            | NULL        |
+--------------+-------------+  | 5             | 4            | NULL        |
                                +---------------+--------------+-------------+
```

What I am hoping to get from this query is equipment_id 2 and 3, but currently I only get 4 and 2. I know it seems I could simply type 'SELECT equipment_id WHERE return_date IS NOT NULL', but the equipment table also has names and it is the names I really want. I already know how to display the names once I get the correct ids.

This is the query I have tried and don't know where to go from here.

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.equipment_id
FROM equipment AS e
LEFT JOIN circulation AS c
ON e.equipment_id = c.equipment_id
WHERE c.return_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT e.equipment_id, e.name
FROM equipment AS e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM circulation AS c
  WHERE e.equipment_id = c.equipment_id AND c.return_date IS NULL
)
```

or with a join of the tables, grouping by `equipment_id` and the conditions in HAVING clause:

```
SELECT e.equipment_id
FROM equipment AS e LEFT JOIN circulation AS c
ON e.equipment_id = c.equipment_id
GROUP BY e.equipment_id
HAVING SUM(c.return_date IS NULL) = 0 OR MAX(c.equipment_id) IS NULL
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.